# SQL multiplying values from 2 tables and printing statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

after calculating `sum(frequency * weight)` from 2 different tables, i am trying to print out a statement (below) if the sum is greater than a certain number, but i keep getting an error that says `total` is not a valid column.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @total INT

SELECT SUM(frequency * weight) AS total
  FROM WF, WW
 WHERE WF.word = WW.word

IF total > 30
BEGIN
  print 'Alert! Bullying post'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  print'Normal Post'
END
```

Comment: You declared a variable, but don't assign the value to it or subsequently use it.

Comment: Please including only a single (is it MySQL or SQL Server?) vendor/version as a tag. Also, include the *exact error message* (I suspect it has been incorrectly represented here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Total as Int;

select @Total = Sum( WF.Frequency * WW.Weight )
  from WF inner join
    WW on WW.Word = WF.Word;

print case when @Total > 30 then 'Alert! Bullying post!' else 'Normal post.' end;
```